# SQL conexion a base de datos con c# (pregunta sobre hosts)

Tags: c#, sql, base-de-datos

Estaba interesada en conectar una aplicación en c#.net a una base de datos de mysql, estoy usando las referecias que ofrece la página oficial de mysql, en este caso la siguiente.

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
```

He probado diferentes hosts dónde alojar mi base de datos, (freehosting) como por ejemplo 000webhost, y éstos famosos, pero ninguno me conecta bien, he probado con páginas que ofrecen unicamente la base de datos, y con éstas no tengo problema, pero o son muy limitadas, o expiran. ¿A qué se debe que con éstas si pueda conectarme? ¿conocéis alguna página sin muchas limitaciones y gratuita?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Saludos hermana, bienvenida a SOes. Prueba Azure, te dan una BD gratis de unos cuantos megas para hacer pruebas, ideal en entornos sencillos. Otra opción es usar AmazonWS.

Comment: He estado echándole un vistazo a ambas páginas pero actualmente no dispongo de ninguna tarjeta de crédito con la que realizar la subscripcion gratuita. ¿Es posible que exista alguna otra alternativa? Muchas gracias :) @fredyfx

Comment: Podría funcionar si consigues una tarjeta de crédito prepago Visa o Mastercard, así lo hice en un inicio con Azure. Si estás en el instituto o en la universidad, consigue la mochila de GitHub https://education.github.com/pack donde Digital Ocean te da 50$ en crédito, considera que la instancia más pequeña es de 5$ al mes, lo que te daría 10 meses para jugar con el servidor virtual privado y con eso tendrías la experiencia de poner cosas en producción; de ser este el caso recomiendo usar Virtualmin https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-utilize-virtualmin-on-a-vps

Comment: de nada mi estimada :D espero te sea de utilidad lo mencionado en este comentario :D

Comment: Hola! finalmente conseguí que me prestasen una tarjeta para poder disfrutar de los meses gratis, y funciona todo a la perfeción. (Probé con amazon, con Azure aún no intenté nada), así que muchísimas gracias por todo :P

Comment: de nada! cuando gustes, aquí toda la hermandad de SOes estamos para servir :D un abrazote